# Implement date range pattern in PHP Glob pattern

Tags: php

I have to search directory names in **PHP**. I have a date range and the folder names contains the date on which they were created. So I need to implement a date range pattern in glob function.

**Edit :** Like I have to get the directories which were created between `10/11/2016` to `12/11/2016`. The directory name is saved like `H1346579_20161110123456`
So, here the date is written in `20161110`. I have to search this pattern in directory names.

Comment: Can you please add any test case or example in your question for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Change `20161110` `20161111` as disired.

```
foreach(glob('you_dir/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $mydir) 
{
    if (preg_match('/20161110|20161111/i', $mydir)) {
    $array_dirs[] = $mydir;
    echo "<br> ";      
    echo $mydir;
}}
```

or in case you want an array `print_r($array_dirs);`